# Data migration between two identical databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need some help regarding an issue i'm having.

I need to migrate data from one database (ex. database1) to another database (ex. database2).

Both have the same structure but they're not in the same server and there's no communication between the servers, ultimately according to the client i can have a backup of the database1 to be restored on the server where the database2 is installed.

The problem is that i have a bunch of tables with identity seeded columns wich their data need to be exported to the database2, and i've maintain the relationships between the main tables. My problem is that the database2 has also identity ids wich are the same but their data is different. here's an exemple:

**Database1**

table_customer
id = 1
name = John Wood
...

table_workplace
id = 20
name = Europe

table_relation
id_customer = 1
id_worlplace = 20

**Database2**

table_customer
id = 1
name = Eric Bloomfield
...

table_relation
id_customer = 1
id_worlplace = 20

table_workplace
id = 20
name = Asia

I need to build a script to import these tables against the database2, is there a simple way to import all data and prevent data loss or broken relationships?

Many thanks and kind regards
Eric

Comment: Research `SQL Server log shipping` and see if that suits your needs.

Comment: Did you have the backup from database server 1 restored to 2?

Comment: do you need one time data migration or you need data changes to be migrated when they occur ?.also please elaborate on  `here's no communication between the servers`

Comment: Hi TheGameiswar, thank you for your time, It's a one time data migration, when i say there's no communication between the servers i meant to say that the databases don't communicate with each other

Comment: Hi WEI_DBA, many thanks for your help, I'm currently checking with the client's team to have a backup of the databaser server 1 restored to 2.

Comment: I'm also thinking in doing it by exporting xml from each tables on database 1 and importing it into database 2 but i have the same problem regarding  the identity columns :( .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could turn IDENTITY_INSERT to ON on your destination tables, then inserting the records from the source increasing ID by a certain amount.

Suppose we have a table, named Test01, with three records, and a table named Test02 having the same structure and different data (except ID, which is the same on both tables). Wanting to add the data of Test02 to Test01, we can set IDENTITY_INSERT to ON on Test01, proceeding in copying the records increasing the ID from Test02.

In code, a thing like that:

```
CREATE TABLE Test01 (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), SomeText VARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE Test02 (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), SomeText VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO Test01(SomeText) VALUES('001'), ('002'), ('003')
INSERT INTO Test02(SomeText) VALUES('A'), ('B'), ('C')

SELECT * FROM Test01
SELECT * FROM Test02
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Test01 ON
GO

INSERT INTO Test01(Id, SomeText) SELECT Id + 10000, SomeText FROM Test02
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Test01 OFF
GO

SELECT * FROM Test01
SELECT * FROM Test02

DROP TABLE Test01
DROP TABLE Test02
GO
```

Executing the script will result in those steps:

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjPgg.png)

Obviously, the ID increase must be done on all related tables, specifying the same amount for each. For situations with a great number of tables that approach can be uncomfortable, though.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello hypnos, many thanks for your time, i'm reconsidering doing this way, i have a lot of tables and it's like you said with  a great number of tables is ver uncomfortable :(  but if it is the only way i have to do it .

Comment: You're welcome. You can also consider to write down a simple program (C# for example) which will produce the SQL script for you.

Comment: For the relantionship tables i'm thinking doing it this way: `select 'UPDATE ' + object_name(object_id ) + ' SET COLUMN_ID = <NewValue> WHERE COLUMN_ID = <OldValue> ' 
from sys.all_columns 
where name = 'COLUMN_ID'` but offcouse for each table that has those relationship columns